# Removing leading spaces from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like follows

```
 abc, def tgy, awed djdj
```

Now i want to get all the parts of this string seperated by comma. Best way i can image is doing the following

```
final String[] splits = country.split(",");
```

Now i should have a array with 3 strings. But i dont want the leading spaces in each string also. How can i remove them. Is there a special way to do that? Or i have to use the same old regex way to remove the leading spaces.

Comment: [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to remove leading/trailing spaces from split elements:

```
final String[] splits = country.trim().split(" *, *");
```

Comment: `country` shall be `trim()`-med as well before splitted.

Answer (score 1):

use this call on a string to remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
arbitraryVariable = arbitraryVariable.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
,\s*
```

You can split by this as well.This will remove leading spaces.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/13